# SQL: UNION realestate priorities offers

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i'm trying to write a sql query to list all offers from database but first to retrive priorities NOT NULL order by rand then priorities NULL order by id.

I`ve made some kind of this:

```
(SELECT anunt_lista_id 
 FROM anunturi__lista
 WHERE anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY RAND())
UNION
(SELECT anunt_lista_id
 FROM anunturi__lista
 WHERE anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NULL
 ORDER BY anunt_lista_id ASC)
LIMIT 100
```

but ORDER BY is ignored, no one is applied.

There is another way to this and using another way to do RAND() because as i know this is too slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER BY in individual parts of UNION is only useful when you add a LIMIT clause to that specific part, otherwise it is ignored.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies
>   nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result
>   because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore,
>   the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with
>   LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows
>   to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect
>   the order of those rows in the final UNION result. If ORDER BY appears
>   without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have
>   no effect anyway.

If you want the first part of the results to be sorted first, you have to workaround it in some way:

```
(SELECT anunt_lista_id 
 FROM anunturi__lista 
 WHERE anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NOT NULL)
UNION
(SELECT anunt_lista_id 
 FROM anunturi__lista 
 WHERE anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NULL)
ORDER BY (anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NULL) ASC,
      CASE WHEN anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NOT NULL THEN 
         RAND() 
      ELSE anunt_lista_id END
LIMIT 100
```

The first clause of the order by: (anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NULL) ASC is going to give false (0) when it isn't NULL and true (1) when it is NULL. Since it is ordering ASC, 0 will appear first than 1.

Comment: And how can i use another alternatives of RAND() in this case? As i know RAND() is too slowly and is recommended to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can make dummy columns for order by!

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 if(anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NOT NULL, rand() , 0) as fld_1, 
 if(anunt_lista_is_prioritar IS NULL,anunt_lista_id  , 0) as fld_2,
 anunt_lista_id 
 FROM anunturi__lista
 order by fld_1 desc , fld_2 asc
 Limit 100
```